# How can I overlap goroutines?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I have three gorutines, which should work in some sort of loop. For example, I have

```
go first() {
    // do some stuff
}
 
go second() {
    // do another kind of stuff
}

go third() {
    // do third kind of stuff
}
```

And they have to work like that:
First - second - third - first - */and so on and so on/*

I guess I have to use channels fo that, but I can't figure out proper way to do so.
If I make three different channels
*FirstToSecond*,
*SeocndToThird*,
*ThirdToFirst*, then when I run a program, I get error:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

But if I get rid of *ThirdToFirst*, I have one proper loop, and then gorutines start to work randomly.

I'm certainly missing something, but what?

Example code with two gorutines

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    ch1 := make(chan struct{})
    ch2 := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        for _, value := range []int{1, 3, 5} {
            <- ch1
            fmt.Println(value)
            ch2 <- struct{}{}    
        } 
        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        for _, value := range []int{2, 4, 6} {
            <- ch2
            fmt.Println(value)
            ch1 <- struct{}{}
        } 
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], something we can compile, run and see. Thanks

Comment: This makes no sense. If they have to execute serially, Put them all in one go routine. It seem like you simply want `for { first(); second(); third(); }`

Comment: @rustyx added example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need such sequencing, you might reevaluate your need to use goroutines. However, the way you described the solution is correct:

```
go first() {
  for {
    <-ch1
    // do stuff
    ch2<-struct{}{}
  } 
}()

go second() {
  for {
    <-ch2
    // do stuff
    ch3<-struct{}{}
  } 
}()

go third() {
  for {
    <-ch3
    // do stuff
    ch1<-struct{}{}
  } 
}()
```

However, this is a circular setup, and you have to start the first one outside this structure:

```
go first() {...}()
go second() {...}()
go third() {...} ()

// Start the first one
ch1<-struct{}{}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Should've thought about that. Any idea why it doesn't work if I type ```ch1 <- struct{}{}``` before starting gorutines? Is it because ch1 is not active yet or something?

Comment: Because the first goroutine starts waiting to receive from the third, which never comes.